# Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

```
SELECT product_name.productname,pr_info.year, 
pr_info.specifications, pr_info.price, company.company_name, 
company.country   
FROM product_name  
left OUTER join  
 (select *  from pr_info  left join company on company.id_company=pr_info.id_company)  
 on product_name.id_productname=pr_info.id_productname
```

Выдает "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Как исправить ошибку? В SQL я новичок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Every derived table must have its own alias - Каждая производная таблица должна иметь свой собственный псевдоним

То есть запрос который в скобках должен иметь псевдоним(алиас). `(select * from ...) AS alias`

Хороший пример дал @Yaroslav, можете видеть что в его вложенного запроса есть тот самый алиас

```
(SELECT * FROM pr_info 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN company 
     ON company.id_company = pr_info.id_company) AS pr_info`
```

Псевдоним присваивается ключевым словом `AS`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_name.productname, 
       pr_info.year, 
       pr_info.specifications, 
       pr_info.price, 
       company.company_name, 
       company.country   
  FROM product_name  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM pr_info 
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN company 
                       ON company.id_company = pr_info.id_company) AS pr_info
    ON product_name.id_productname = pr_info.id_productname
```